# Why does valgrinds timings not match with timings reported by the application?

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind

My applications outputted timing and valgrinds are in disagreement.

```
QTime myTimer;
myTimer.start();

Content *items = Content_getContent(path);
int get_content = myTimer.elapsed();
this->content->setContent(items);

int total = myTimer.elapsed();
printf("ListPane::setPath(getContent) -- %d ms\n", get_content);
printf("ListPane::setPath(setContent) -- %d ms\n", total-get_content);
printf("ListPane::setPath(Total)      -- %d ms\n", total);
fflush(0);
```

Produces the output:

```
ListPane::setPath(getContent) -- 54004 ms
ListPane::setPath(setContent) -- 132963 ms
ListPane::setPath(Total)      -- 186967 ms
```

Valgrind reports, however:

```
Content_getContent            : 64.24%
ContentListWidget::setContent : 35.65%
```

Empirically I tend to agree with the programs output (based on how the UI responds). This begs the question, however, why is valgrind reporting incorrect timings?

Comment: What times are being measured? CPU time? Real time?

Comment: @amdn Because valgrind is an external utility that is used for debugging and profiling code, which produces its own output.

Comment: @Kaz well, my code is real time, obviously. I must admit that I hadnt thought that valgrind might not record real time. I ran it with default arguments `sudo valgrind --tool=callgrind ./foo`. So would that be cpu time? does it matter though? shouldnt the ratios match?

Comment: Does set content call get content?

Comment: @Yakk no sir it doesnt.

Comment: can anyone explain the downvote? this is a legitimate question.

Comment: The percentages you see with cal grind are a measure of CPU use, not wall time.